# C# name from string

Tags: c#, .net

I can't find information about this.
I need to make a lot of items, and it looks like this:

```
Bar01.Value = data[0];
Bar02.Value = data[1];
Bar03.Value = data[2];
Bar04.Value = data[3];
Bar05.Value = data[4];
Bar06.Value = data[5];
...
Bar99999.Value = data[99998]
etc.
```

Is there a way to make a string for it like

```
for(int i=0;i<max;i++)
string s = "Bar"+i;
//do stuff
```

So that it would be shorter ?

Comment: all data are same type?

Comment: yes, they're integers

Comment: so, you can use Dictionary. But why you want to copy it form array?

Comment: There is usually never a goood reason to instantiate a ridiculously large collection in memory. Better to create a Factory type that can return a specific item on request (based on some TBD parameters). As the question stands now what you are actually trying to accomplish is not very clear.

Comment: If you think you want to have 99,999 variables... don't. If you tell us how they are used, we might be able to give you a better solution.

Comment: Oh, I just made this up quickly to show the problem I had.

I'm actually using an array of 32 integers, and creating 32 lines of ctrl+c/ctrl+v code seemed silly to me

Comment: you should have better solution. Don't waste variable like this.

Comment: But if you have array why you need variables?

Comment: What represents "Barxx"? are those controls? classes? something else?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Dictionary` in this way:

```
Dictionary<string, int> dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
for(int i=0;i<max;i++)
{
    dict["Bar" + i] = data[i];
}
```